# formalization of coordinate-free linear algebra in a proof assistant

Tags: linear-algebra, coq, isabelle, proof

I am aware of projects that formalize linear algebra in existing proof assistants (i.e. Coq), but it seems like most of them are based on matrices. I was wondering if it's done in a coordinate-free way, with operations like taking tensor/wedge powers and dualizing. If so, at least in the finite dimensional case, can one coordinatize and work with matrices?

Comment: I have the impression that some of these operations would be hard to define in Coq in a coordinate-free manner without the use of extra axioms or the setoid machinery.  For instance, the tensor product of two vector spaces is built as a quotient, which is cannot be defined in full generality in Coq.

Comment: So are there any other systems based on constructive type theory that are capable of doing quotients? If so, where can I find a good discussion of the subject matter?

Comment: The "setoid machinery" mentioned before is one way of allowing Coq to define quotients - though currently it tends to be noisy.  Another way, if you don't care about being able to do computations using the definitions, is to assume a subset extensionality axiom (along with a definite description axiom needed to define induced functions on quotients) and then use the classical construction of "the type of equivalence classes".

Comment: @DanielSchepler Are there any good bite-sized examples and/or literature I can look into?

Comment: ``So are there any other systems based on constructive type theory that are capable of doing quotients? If so, where can I find a good discussion of the subject matter?" The [Nuprl proof assistant](http://www.nuprl.org/) implements constructive type theory and has quotient types.